# How do you query for embedded objects from a repository with Spring Data?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I've got an object, let's call it an `Item`. Speaking conceptually, users can perform actions against these items. The actions should be persisted as history for the items.

My document root is `Item`, and it has `Action`'s embedded within it.

I have created spring data repository:

```
public interface Item extends CrudRepository<Item, String>
```

Is it possible to create a method, perhaps by annotating it somehow with `@Query`, that would grab a list of `Action`'s that match certain criteria? I want to grab this data in order to show a user recent history across all `Item`'s.

Would a better approach to put `Action`'s in their own document type and link them to their `Item`'s?

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to query `Action` you can use method called with the following pattern:

```
findByAction_{actionPropertyName}
```

Or if it won't be ambiguous you can remove the underscore.

1.3.2.2.1. Property expressions from http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/

Comment: That's really cool. I didn't know you could do that, thanks!

What I am really getting at is that I want the query to return a List<Action> not a List<Item>. It just so happens that the Action's only exist being embedded within Item's, so there's probably no straightforward way to do that.

Comment: Have you found a solution to what you are doing?